Optimize std::vector comparison to memcmp
Consider the following code (https://godbolt.org/z/Tjf4csba4):
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

struct box {
    unsigned char x;
    bool operator==(const box& other) const = default;
};

template <typename T>
struct container {
    std::vector<T> v;

    bool equals_vec(const container<T>& b1, const container<T>& b2) {
        return b1.v == b2.v;
    }

    bool equals_memcmp(const container<T>& b1, const container<T>& b2) {
        return b1.v.size() == b2.v.size() &&
            std::memcmp(b1.v.data(), b2.v.data(), b1.v.size()*sizeof(T)) == 0;
    }
};

template class container<box>;

because the comparison operator is trivial, the two equal_* functions do the same thing, of course the memcmp one is much faster.
I would really like the compiler to figure it out by itself, but I imagine that it's not possible (though I'd like to learn why).
So the next best thing is to constrain T in container so that the memcmp comparison is valid for such type and use that to implement equality.
I've seen in this more general question that the problem had no conclusive solution in C++20, did the landscape change in C++23? Or is there some custom concept I can write out that makes it safe?

Here is the requested benchmark: https://quick-bench.com/q/k8m93TAYjJKcNk27gnRyNRQsJ8Q
and the execution example: https://godbolt.org/z/ad8oThYhs

Obligatory question: Is this an optimising build?

@catnip Yes, see godbolt link.

I might be wrong, but what if compiler assumes the code might be executed from multiple threads, so the outcomes of two methods might differ in fact, and instead of guessing the compiler just calls whatever you requested (i.e. element wise comparison operator in first case, versus check of size and then comparison of memory footprints byte-wise)

OK, sorry, missed that.  Did you actually benchmark it?  What is the speedup?  You can use https://quick-bench.com

On the reasoning, "the memcmp one is much faster" - what makes you think so? Do you have performance measurements or this is just a speculation (can you share the performance measurement results, https://quick-bench.com/ might help)? On the topic, your godbolt link doesn't have executable code which could show how exactly you want to see it.

Typical usecase is to compare a ~1000 elements vector, speedup in real code is about 3x (approximately), not far from the naive 4x I'd expect from a 64b comparison.

@AlexeyS.Larionov The compiler is under no obligation to make code threadsafe.  That is down to you.

@DamirTenishev benchmark here: https://quick-bench.com/q/k8m93TAYjJKcNk27gnRyNRQsJ8Q
Could be benchmarked better, but the difference is clear.

Libc++ does this optimization by itself, see https://godbolt.org/z/TKov8Exq8. Although technically memcmp should be worse assuming optimal implementations, because it has stricter requirements on the value it returns than necessary and because it can't assume the alignment to be anything but 1 (std::vector<box>::operator== could in theory use that std::allocator::allocate has stronger alignment guarantees).

@user17732522 that's interesting, so is this a missed optimization that should be filed to the libstdc++ devs?

@12345ieee I guess you can suggest it if the benchmarks are convincing. It doesn't seem obvious for me from just the code.

@user17732522 the naive benchmark (see link above) is a 33x speedup, of course it would have to be benchmarked a bit better, as I've never used that site before, but it looks pretty big to me.

@12345ieee The difference probably comes mainly from libstdc++ using a short-circuiting loop to implement operator==. That makes it hard for the compiler to optimize. If you use a non-short-circuiting loop instead, you get close (at least with Clang). See https://quick-bench.com/q/qAvl2PsYXnLnD8jDYormaln9HEY (and that can probably be written better).

@user17732522 I see, so I guess libstdc++ optimizes for the "small vector and hard comparison" case by default while libc++ goes for the "large vector and easy comparison".
At this point my original question remains, how do I constrain T so this is safe.

@12345ieee You can't portably. libc++ uses a compiler built-in for that purpose which you can't implement in standard C++ (__is_trivially_equality_comparable). Of course, if you are using Clang you could just use the built-in.

@user17732522 this is what was concluded in the linked question. can you turn your great comments in an answer, so I can upvote and then see if there's some gcc trick someone else knows in c++23

Thanks for the benchmark comparison. On the "At this point my original question remains, how do I constrain T so this is safe", my question is still remains: "your godbolt link doesn't have executable code which could show how exactly you want to see it."; I mean, could you show a way you want to see this in the code if implemented in the way you are looking for (with main function and calls)?

@DamirTenishev added to the question
